# Bitbucket pipeline installing the wrong version of cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

When I apt-get install cmake in my Bitbucket pipeline, it installs version 3.0.2. This then leads to an error "CMake 3.7.2 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.0.2". How can I install cmake version 3.7.2 or higher in my .yml?

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: gcc:6.5

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake
          - cmake -B build .
```

Error:

```
+ cmake -B build .
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.7.2 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.0.2
```

Comment: Did you see the responses to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line)?

Comment: @squareskittles The top responses recommend to "Go to the official CMake webpage, then download and extract the latest version". I don't believe this is possible to automate in my .yml. (I'm new to pipelines so I may be confused here)

Comment: You may just be able to put all of those commands in your `script:` section, to replace the `apt-get` install commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a pipelines issue. I'll walk through the troubleshooting process to identify the problem and a possible solution. You could pursue other solutions to install your desired version but hopefully following the approach here will help you in future.

Full disclosure, I work for Atlassian - though not on the Bitbucket Pipelines team :)

---

The version of `cmake` that you see being installed is actually related to the third party base image you're using, `gcc:6.5`. You can test/verify this on your own machine:

```
$ docker run --rm -it gcc:6.5 bash
root@77d4fde67119:/# apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake
root@77d4fde67119:/# cmake --version
cmake version 3.0.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

We can see the `gcc:6.5` image is based on Debian Jessie:

```
root@77d4fde67119:/# cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
```

If you look up the default `cmake` package for Jessie you'll find that it's v3.0.2: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/devel/cmake

A little more digging will show you that newer Debian versions package newer versions of `cmake` by default: Stretch or Buster will package 3.7 or 3.13 respectively. So the solution to your issue is using a newer version of the `gcc` base image based on a more recent Debian version:

Let's try it again with the `gcc:7` base image:

```
$ docker run --rm -it gcc:7 bash
root@26e82f7b5e56:/# cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

Well, that's a good sign: `gcc:7` is based on Debian Buster. Buster ships 3.13: https://packages.debian.org/buster/devel/cmake

```
root@26e82f7b5e56:/# apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake
root@26e82f7b5e56:/# cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.4

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

There you have it: a version above 3.7.

If you can't use this version of `gcc`, of course, you'll need to look at a different solution. But hopefully this helps to illustrate the source of your issue and how you can investigate these kinds of issues in future.